# formatting numbers(spellout) with icu4j

Tags: java, icu

I want to localize numbers by spelling them out with a locale and ended up using ICU4J. 
I succeeded in many locales but didn't seem to get it done for a few like Georgian, Turkish or Arabic.

```
ULocale locale = new ULocale("Tr");  //Turkish
Double d = Double.parseDouble(input);
NumberFormat formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(locale, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
String result = formatter.format(d);
```

When I debug the ruleset inside by formatter object seems empty and it prints out in English(as default I guess).

In ICU website it is written that:
*ICU provides number spellout rules for several locales, but not for all of the locales that ICU supports, and not all of the predefined rule types. Also, as of release 2.6, some of the provided rules are known to be incomplete.*

But it seems ICU's own demo page can do it for that locales too(http://demo.icu-project.org/icu4jweb/numero.jsp)

I also can locate *.res* files in the *icu5j-53.1.jar* under my *.m2* folder 
(*\icu4j-53.1\com\ibm\icu\impl\data\icudt53b\rbnf*)

Would appreciate any help about how the demo page can manage to do it and why I can't?

Comment: I've tried locally with your code, and the same version of icu4j, and I get correct Turkish output.

Comment: I've also tried with version 3.4.4, and then my output is in English. Could you check your (transitive) dependencies and make sure that you're not pulling an old version in somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You were right, i checked my dependency tree and some other library is depending on an  earlier (4.0) version of it. After fixing it, i started getting Turkish output.

Comment: Good news! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested your code with version 53.1 and got correct Turkish output. I then retested with version 3.4.4 and got English output as you described in your question.

Most likely, you are pulling in an older version through a transitive maven dependency.

Comment: Version 56.1 works pretty well for me most locales including "Tr", Maven dependency below, in case it helps:
`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>56.1</version>
</dependency>
`